# Figure out if object has a specific key

Tags: typescript

```
const a = {
    b: "hello",
    c: "world",
}

function f(x: keyof typeof a | { x: string }) {

}

function g(x: string) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        return f(x);
    } else {
        return f({ x });
    }
}
```

The `g` function takes in a string `x`. If `x` is a key of `a` (`"b"` or `"c"`), then it should call the `f` function with `x` as the sole argument. If `x` is NOT a key of `a`, then the `g` function has to call the `f` function with an object which has the `x` string inside it.

However, this code errors when calling the `f(x)` function. It seems like TypeScript doesn't understand that after using `hasOwnProperty`, the `x` string is a keyof `a`. Is there some way to make TypeScript understand this **without** resorting to type assertions?

[TypeScript Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20a%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%22hello%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%22world%22%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20f(x%3A%20keyof%20typeof%20a%20%7C%20%7B%20x%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20g(x%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(a.hasOwnProperty(x))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20f(x)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20f(%7B%20x%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Note that it's perfectly allowed to write `let a = { hasOwnProperty: (x: string) => true };`, so `a.hasOwnProperty(x)` being true does not guarantee *in general* that `x` is a key of `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest with a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isInA(x: string): x is keyof typeof a {
    return a.hasOwnProperty(x);
}

if (isInA(x)) {
    return f(x);
}
```